# Copying Data from another Excel Workbook based on a matching id

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 2 workbooks I am working with.

- One workbook has an id and a category name.
- The other workbook shows a name and category section that has an id number (but not the actual description).

Basically I want to copy the full category text to my current workbook from the old one based on the id number into a new column

What kind of formula can I use to check the id number category pair and then copy it into the new workbook in a new column?

Any help is great!

Answer (score 1):

Old worksheet:
Column A: ID
The following columns will have descriptions for the ID.

New worksheet: 
Column A: ID

Cells with a formula will contain information from the old WB (next column to ID for the formula below):

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,[OldWBName]Sheet1!$A$1:$F$1000,2)
```

The formula can be copied down, after copying right, ",2)" should be changed to ",3)" etc. to include the next column.

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php gives a good overview.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `vlookup` function or otherwise use a VBA script. When you have tried something come back to this forum and ask a specific question please.